# Maintain inner for loop until end of List array

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I use **continue** to go back to the **start of the 2nd for loop** to go to the next iteration it does not work. I have used break and some thing. I do not know what else to do. my cod below. basically after the end of the test or if a condition is false i want to go back to the 2nd for loop iteration.

```
 for (String client: Arrayclients) {

   // do some stuff

   //** Begin *2nd inner for-loop****

   for (int i = 0; i < links; i++) {

    PS_OBJ_CycleData.ScrollToTop(driver); // scroll up
    List < WebElement > CCTable = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector));
    WebElement code = CCTable.get(i);
    // changing code to mcode to look for first 3 characters    
    String mcode = code.getText().substring(0, 3).trim();
    System.out.println("\n" + "modified " + mcode);
    // System.out.println("\n"+code.getText().substring(0, 3).trim()+"\n");

    //----------------------checking for bad code -----------------------------------------
    String[] badcodes = {
     "5H9",
     "5GJ",
     "5AX",
     "5A4",
     "5HD"
    };
    boolean check = Arrays.asList(badcodes).contains(mcode);
    System.out.println(check + "code in array list");
    //check == true will work as well
    if (check) {
     System.out.println(check + "-Bad Code found breaking loop");
     continue;
    } else {
     //checking to make sure element is clickable
     PS_OBJ_CycleData.isClickable(code, driver);
     System.out.println("Clickable?" + code.isEnabled());
     code.click();
    }



    for (WebElement cc: MulCCodeProcess) {

    }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    PS_OBJ_CycleData.PreviewPayroll(driver).click();
    PS_OBJ_CycleData.VerifyCalcPreviewPayrollBox(driver);

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; i++) {
     String PreviewStatus = "//table[@id='cppProcessInfoTable_rows_table']//tr[@id='cppProcessInfoTable_row_0']/td[starts-with(@id,'cppProcessInfoTable_row_0_cell_2')]";

     List < WebElement > Status = driver.findElements(By.xpath(PreviewStatus));
     WebElement status = Status.get(x);
     String pstatus = status.getText().trim();
     System.out.println("\n" + "status " + pstatus);

     String Status1 = "Complete";
     String Status2 = "Sucessfull";
     String Status3 = "Payroll Delayed";
     String Status4 = "Error";

     WebElement CalcPreviewPayroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'cppBatch_title')]"));

     if (CalcPreviewPayroll.isDisplayed() && pstatus.equals(Status1) || pstatus.equals(Status2)) {
      PS_OBJ_CycleData.Close(driver).click();
      break;
     }

     if (!CalcPreviewPayroll.isDisplayed()) {
      break;
     }

     if (CalcPreviewPayroll.isDisplayed() && pstatus.equals(Status3) || pstatus.equals(Status4)) {
      PS_OBJ_CycleData.Close(driver).click();
      PS_OBJ_CycleData.VerifyCycleStatusID(driver);
      System.out.println("breaking loop cause " + pstatus);
      continue;
     }

    }

    // do some stuff

   } //** END 2nd inner for-loop****

  } //**END outter for-loop****
```

Comment: You've included way too much code. Consider re-writing your post.

Comment: Okay give me a 1 will

Comment: Have you removed break and checked?

Comment: Yes I changed the break with continue and it does not code back to the 2nd loop and if it does it is not picking up the next iteration of code form the list

Comment: @ElroyJetson I just cleaned it up

Comment: The continue in the 1st section of the 2nd for loop works but as i go down further and use break or continue it dose not pick up where it left off

Comment: @Deepan I cleaned up the code

Comment: So what happens if you use continue? What are the observable results?

Comment: Your best bet is to learn how to debug. Look up the documentation for your IDE, learn how to place breakpoints, and execute the script in debug mode and watch the code flow. There's so much code here and so much code missing, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: When I use continue it goes looks like it is going back to the 2nd loop but then just reverts to the outer loop. could it be that it cant find the next iteration?

Comment: I can post this section of the code if you want that is more readable

Comment: I am kinda late to the party, and it seems you have edited your code. Now there is no `continue` statement anywhere. So your question no longer makes sense. Have you read how to create [mcve]?

Comment: @SiKing I gave more code detail

Comment: Can you share a link to the site?

Comment: @JeffC  What do you mean? This is my custom code i am coding in eclipse?

Comment: I can share the link i am using to Java online formater that has my code do you want that?

Comment: Your script is operating on a website... share a link to the page on that website so we can see if there's a better way to accomplish what you are attempting.

Comment: @JeffC Oh this is an internal site i am testing on my job

Comment: The problem is that it is that the 2nd continue is down at the end of my code... when it is executed its like it tried but goes directly to the outer for loop my code is above

Comment: I am debugging but no success what do now its it is going directly to the outer loop

Comment: @JeffC I found one issue i had this for (int x = 0; x < 9; i++) instead of for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) could that cause the problem?

Comment: I found the problem and corrected it what i stated above did throw my program off and the continue for the inner 4 loop should not be in there because i need to continue from the 4 loop outside. i should have just used break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really certain of what you mean by "2nd" loop. For clarity I will refer to the loops as inner and outer.

`continue` is used to essentially skip to the next iteration of the loop in which `continue` is inside of. Therefore, if you have a nested loop, placing continue inside the inner loop, will skip to the next iteration of itself. `continue` won't have any effect on the outer loop if inside of the inner loop.

If this is not what's happening, then either something is wrong with Java, or something is wrong with your logic somewhere. I doubt that something is wrong with Java.

Try using your debugger to figure out what the values are of variables associated with your conditional. Your debugger can help you better than we can.

Comment: I meant 2nd for loop

Comment: I used continue inside the 2nd loop there must be something wrong with my logic because when go to my else statement and click continue it pauses and then executes the code in my outer loop

Comment: Okay for some reason when when continue is executed it is bypassing the inner loop it is in and going to the outer loop.. however I need help as to know why because when continue is used in the 1st part of the code it works just fine. is there a limit on how many times you can use continue?

Comment: I found one issue i had this  for (int x = 0; x < 9; i++)  instead of  for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) could that cause the problem?

Comment: I understand now that i was using continue in the wrong way. Thanks I had to leave the code and come back with a clear head

Comment: It happens. Glad we could help